# Paraview in Ubuntu

Tags: opengl

I am now using Paraview alongside Openfoam. I have a problem regarding the viewing of my model. Whenever I click Apply, the model appears, and after a while, it disappears. Then whenever I try to click on something, there's an error that says in the terminal

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error paraview:
../../../../src/mesa/vbo/vbo_exec_draw.c:222: vbo_exec_bind_arrays: Assertion `exec->vtx.bufferobj->Mappings[MAP_INTERNAL].Pointer' failed.
```

What can be the problem? I used paraview before, and I have no problem., the version that I've used before is 4.0 or 4.4. Thank you for your consideration on this matter. God Bless and more power :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Paraview to visualize my simulation results on Ubuntu 16.04. However, with the recent update to version Paraview 5.3.0, I wasn't able to use 'opacity' and 'Slice' operations.

Paraview would crash with the following error:

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error paraview: segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

It seems to be a problem with the OpenGL drivers. So, I upgraded it now, and it works fine! Following were the commands in terminal

```
apt-add-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
apt-get update 
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a legacy problem with Paraview 4.x with some input files. Simply download and install [the latest version](http://www.paraview.org/download/) using the binary files. Make sure your graphic card and openGL drivers are up to date.

It should solve the problem.